# Support of cocycles, coboundaries and cohomology of a Koszul complex

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a variety, $F$ is a vector bundle of rank $r$ on $X$ and $s \in \Gamma(X,F)$ a section. Then we have dual section $s^\vee: F^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_X$, cokernel of the dual section is the structure sheaf of the vanishing locus $Z$ of $s$ i.e. $\operatorname{coker}(s^\vee)=\mathcal{O}_Z$. Extending $s^\vee$ by the product rule on the exterior algebra of $F^\vee$ we get the Koszul complex $K(F,s)$:
$$
0\to \wedge^r F^\vee \to \ldots \to \wedge^2 F^\vee \to F^\vee \to \mathcal{O}_X
$$

Is it true that cocycles $Z^i$, coboundaries $B^i$ and cohomology $H^i$ of the Koszul complex are sheaves supported on $Z$?

Comment: This is correct and can be easily checked by localization at points outside $Z$.

Comment: This is true only for cohomology. Cocyles and coboundaries are usually supported on the whole $X$.